# Output of a list of Maybe Int with Just in every element in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes

I have this function which takes an integer n and returns a list of type Maybe Int, containing the unique prime factors. I don't understand why it returns them with **Just** inside every element of the list.

I expect an output like this:

```
primeFactors 75 = Just [3,5]
```

But I have one that  looks like this:

```
primeFactor 75 = [Just 5,Just 3,Just 1]
```

Here is my code:

```
divides :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divides m n = rem m n == 0

transform :: Int -> Int
transform n = (n*2) + 1

isComposite :: Int -> Bool
isComposite n = foldl (||) (divides n 2) (map (divides n) (map (transform) [1..(div n 4)]))

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
 | n <= 0 = error "Makes no sense"
 | n < 4 = True
 | otherwise = not (isComposite n)

primeFactors :: Int -> [Maybe Int]
primeFactors 0 = [Nothing]
primeFactors n = primeFactors2 n ((div n 2)+1)

primeFactors2 :: Int -> Int -> [Maybe Int]
primeFactors2 n 0 = []
primeFactors2 n x
    | divides n x && isPrime x = Just x:primeFactors2 n (x-1)
    | otherwise = primeFactors2 n (x-1)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Maybe` at all?

Comment: It's because my output has to be `Just [3,5]` as said in the specifications of my exercises, but I don't know how to make it work with `Maybe` in the way I am asked.

Comment: I'm guessing the `Maybe` is to handle the case of negative or zero input. You should handle that in a "wrapper" function, and write a "worker" function with no `Maybe`s that expects its input to be strictly positive.

Comment: How can I do that? I am really struggling with the Maybe "wrapper".

Comment: Write the worker first.

Comment: it's probably not good for your exercise but `sequence [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5] == Just [3,4,5]` - but really: just remove the `Maybe`/`Just`from `primeFactors2`, change `primeFactors` to `-> [Int]` and `.. 0 = []` instead of `= [Nothing]` and check the `Nothing`-cases in `factorPrimo`

Comment: To be clear, do you want `primeFactors 0 = Nothing` and `primeFactors 1 = Just []`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: primeFactors needs to be `primeFactors :: Int -> Maybe [Int]`, if I do as recommended it would be `primeFactors :: [Int] -> Maybe [Int]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that I think will do what you want:

```hs
primeFactors :: Int -> Maybe [Int]
primeFactors n 
    | n <= 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ primeFactors2 n n

primeFactors2 :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
primeFactors2 n p
    | n <= 1 || p <= 1 = []
    | divides n p && isPrime p = p : primeFactors2 (n `div` p) p
    | otherwise = primeFactors2 n (p-1)

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
 | n <= 1 = False
 | otherwise = not (isComposite n)

isComposite :: Int -> Bool
isComposite n = 
    any (divides n) [2..n-1]

divides :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divides m n = 
    rem m n == 0
```

Please note that (for clarity's sake I hope) I did remove some of your optimizations and made a major change: this one will report `Just [2,2]` as prime-factors for `4`
(IMO you want `product <$> primeFactors n == Just n`).

If not (as your example indicates) it shouldn't be too hard to fix this (just take your version).

Anyway the only really interesting contribution is how `primeFactor` handles `primeFactors2` to get you the `Maybe` result.